# Mysql: join across five tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a mysql database with this setup (omitting fields not relevant to this question)

```
users
  id                #primary key

user_group_teachers
  id                #primary key
  teacher_id        #foreign key to users.id
  user_group_id     #foreign key to users_groups.id

user_groups
  id                #primary key

user_group_members
  id                #primary key
  pupil_id          #foreign key to pupils.id
  user_group_id     #foreign key to users_groups.id

pupils
  id                #primary key
```

I have a collection of user ids in an array, called "user_ids".

For each of those user ids, i want to collect the pupil ids associated with that user via the

```
user -> user_group_teachers -> user_groups -> user_group_members -> pupils
```

association.  Ie, some kind of join across the tables.

So, i'd like to get some kind of result where the rows look like

```
[1, [6,7,8,9]]
```

where 1 is the teacher id, and [6,7,8,9] are the ids of pupils.  I'd only like each pupil id to appear once in the second list.

Can anyone tell me how to do this in as small a number of queries as possible (or, more broadly, as efficiently as possible).  I will probably usually have between 1000 and 10,000 ids in user_ids.

I'm doing this in a ruby script, so can store the results as variables (arrays or hashes) in between queries, if that makes things simpler.

Thanks!  max
EDIT for Lyhan

Lyhan - thanks but your solution doesn't seem to work.  For example in the first row of the results, using your method, i have

```
| user_id | group_concat(pupils.id separator ",")                                                                         
|       1 | 2292
```

But, if i get the associated pupil ids in a slower, step by step way, then i get different results:

```
select group_concat(user_group_teachers.user_group_id separator ",") 
from user_group_teachers 
where user_group_teachers.teacher_id = 1 
group by user_group_teachers.teacher_id;
```

I get

```
| group_concat(user_group_teachers.user_group_id separator ",")  
| 12,1033,2117,2280,2281
```

Plugging these values (user_group ids) into another query:

```
select group_concat(user_group_members.pupil_id separator ",") 
from user_group_members 
where user_group_members.user_group_id in (12,1033,2117,2280,2281) 
group by user_group_members.user_group_id;
```

I get

```
| group_concat(user_group_members.pupil_id separator ",") 
| 47106,47107
```

Thanks for the group_concat method btw, that's handy :)

Comment: I find it slightly odd that you have a "users" table and a "pupils" table.  Is there a reason for that?  Also, I would like to point out that what you are asking for only requires these three tables: user_groups, user_group_teachers and user_group_members.

Comment: Another question, your db allows a user_group to have more than one teacher - does that affect how you want the data returned? Would you rather see [ [1,2], [6,7,8,9] ] for that case or leave it as two separate results like this [1, [6,7,8,9]], [2, [6,7,8,9]]?

Comment: @DavidFleeman I could see a scenario where you have many users, but only some of them are pupils and you need to store information on pupils that you don't need for other kinds of users. It may also be that pupils are not users at all, and only staff/faculty get access.

Comment: Users and pupils are two different entities: users are teachers, effectively, and pupils are, well, pupils.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, I probably should remove that comment as the thing that was throwing me was that the pupils and users table seem unneeded for the question that was asked.

Comment: I have not had a use for this, but looking around, there is also a GROUP_CONCAT function in mysql that may let you get the list in a single result-set where a returned field would be your comma-delimited list of pupils.  I don't know how useful that would be depending on what additional info you are wanting to pull in the queries after you get the basic query working.

Comment: ah i see: yes, you're right, we only actually need user_group_teachers , user_groups and user_group_members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a couple comments above that are important to the solution for this, but I think you could start with these two queries to see if it gets you far enough along to get what you need.

To get ordered lists for a teacher for pupils across all groups, you could do this:

```
select distinct t.teacher_id, m.pupil_id
from user_groups g
    inner join user_group_teachers t
        on t.user_group_id = g.id
    inner join user_group_members m
        on t.user_group_id = g.id
order by t.teacher_id, m.pupil_id
```

To get ordered lists for a teacher for pupils with the relationship to group in tact, you could do this:

```
select g.id, t.teacher_id, m.pupil_id
from user_groups g
    inner join user_group_teachers t
        on t.user_group_id = g.id
    inner join user_group_members m
        on t.user_group_id = g.id
order by g.id, t.teacher_id, m.pupil_id
```

You would have to walk these result sets and transform them into the nested arrays, but it is the data you wanted.

**Update:** Update: If the data set is too large or you do not want to walk a single result set, then you could do this to emulate the results of the first query above and build your sub-arrays based on query result sets:

```
/* Use this query to drive the batch */
select distinct t.teacher_id
from user_groups_teachers t
order by t.teacher_id

/* Inside a loop based on first query result, pull out the array of pupils for a teacher */
select distinct m.pupil_id
from user_groups_members m
    inner join user_groups g
        on g.id = m.user_group_id
    inner join user_groups_teachers t
        on t.user_group_id = g.id
where t.teacher_id = /* parameter */
order by m.pupil_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i came up with:

```
    select pupil_group_teachers.teacher_id, group_concat(pupil_group_members.pupil_id separator ',') 
    from pupil_group_teachers join pupil_groups on pupil_group_teachers.pupil_group_id = pupil_groups.id
    join pupil_group_members on pupil_group_members.pupil_group_id = pupil_groups.id
    group by pupil_group_teachers.teacher_id;
```

it seems to work, and is really fast.  Lyhan (who has since deleted his answer) and David Fleeman both helped me figure it out.  Cheers guys.